# Solr 9.2 - Dense Vector Search

Tags: search, vector, solr

We are testing ** solr 9.2** with [Dense Vector Search](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/dense-vector-search.html)

First, we edited the **managed-schema.xml**:

```
   
    <fieldType name="knn_vector" class="solr.DenseVectorField" vectorDimension="4"/>  
    <dynamicField name="*_vtr" type="knn_vector" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Then, we restart the Solr.

Next, we created a small collection:

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:8983/api/collections \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "create": {
    "name": "teste7",
    "numShards": 1,
    "replicationFactor": 1
  }
}'
```

Then, we insert and commit the data:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'http://localhost:8983/api/collections/teste7/update' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '  [{ "id": "1",
"vector2_vtr": [1.0, 2.5, 3.7, 4.1]
},
{ "id": "2",
"vector2_vtr": [1.5, 5.5, 6.7, 65.1]
}
]'
```

and

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"set-property":{"updateHandler.autoCommit.maxTime":15000}}' http://localhost:8983/api/collections/teste7/config
```

Here is the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfsbd.png)

Here is the schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV01X.png)

But, when we search

```
q={!knn f=vector2_vtr topK=10}[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

We receive the erros:

```
"error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",       "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],     "msg":"only DenseVectorField is compatible with Knn Query Parser",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1S3i.png)

Dense Vector Search is relatively new and we can not find much information or a complete example.

Any ideal?

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the `vector2_vtr` field was not indexed as DenseVectorField.

In the 'schema image' that was shared, `vector2_vtr` has

```
Field-Type: org.apache.solr.schema.DoublePointField
```

instead of:

```
Field-Type: org.apache.solr.schema.DenseVectorField
```

like in this case:

[image]

Comment: Hi,  


Thanks for your answer!  
  

Note that, “vector2_vtr” was created dynamically when we insert the data using a "curl --request POST ...". But, the type was not created correctly (i.e., DenseVectorField).  
  

Is not possible to create a DenseVectorField dynamically?  What is wrong with my small example?

Comment: Hi! It is possible to create a DenseVectorField dynamically. Could you please share the command used to edit the managed-schema? Are you sure that the managed-schema of teste7 collection includes the changes (since it was created later)? Check with this: http://localhost:8983/solr/teste7/schema

Comment: In general, if you are exploring Dense Vector Search, this blog post https://sease.io/2023/01/apache-solr-neural-search-tutorial.html might come in handy